# i have tried using phpmailer() it gives msg has been sent but i have not received any mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

My log shows as follows 
`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->Port = 587;`

> 017-03-14 09:53:25 
>   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com 
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
>   SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients 
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii 2017-03-14 09:53:27
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: This body in bold! 2017-03-14 09:53:27
>   SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection 63sm14765080wmg.22 - gsmtp Message has been sent

previous code looks to be as follows .
I have changed the port as 465 and SMTPSecure as ssl.
I had different error

> 2017-03-14 07:40:31   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
>   2017-03-14 07:40:31   SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting 
> Message
>   could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I have made changes in php.ini by adding send email password and name.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;       // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();          // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';// Specify main and backup SMTP s
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'sender@gmail.com';                 // SMTP user
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP pas
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';          // Enable TLS  'tls'encryption, 
$mail->Port = 465;                  // TCP port to 

$mail->setFrom('sender@gmail.com', 'Eiman');
$mail->addAddress('sender1@gmail.com', 'user1');
$mail->addAddress('sender2@gmail.com');    // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');     // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);           // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Registration Form';
$mail->Body = 'This body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in ';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Finally i have changed **$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;** `now there is no error . I didn't receive any mail.

Comment: Which version of PHPmailer are you using?

Comment: What hosting service are you using? Digitalocean, for example, blocks smtp for default.  I struggled a lot before finding this out, and turned out that this wasn't my fault haha.

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the links shown? *This is often reported as a PHPMailer problem, but it's almost always down to local DNS failure, firewall blocking (for example as GoDaddy does) or other issue on your local network. It means that PHPMailer is unable to contact the SMTP server you have specified in the Host property, but doesn't say exactly why. It can also be caused by not having the openssl extension loaded (See encryption notes below).*

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this in your gmail account?

[image: Allow less secure app]
   turn it ON

Comment: yes i has done it.

Answer (score 0):

> 017-03-14 09:53:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
>   SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii 2017-03-14 09:53:27
>   CLIENT -> SERVER: This body in bold! 2017-03-14 09:53:27
>   SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection 63sm14765080wmg.22 - gsmtp Message has been sent

This is not an error, see the text **Message has been sent**

What you're seeing here is the output of the `SMTPDebug` log.

So simply comment out your debug log:

```
// $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Comment: SMTPSecure = 'tls' and Port = 587  even after this it shows the above error .

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect that you've tried these changes please

Comment: @iman I have updated my answer. Please review.

Comment: This is a chameleon question. First versions showed a debug log with SMTP connection errors. The OP has been editing it until the code finally worked.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I noticed that after updating my answer, but I didn't have the stamina to pull the OP up about it, and to be honest wasn't certain myself on the best way of correcting this.